# How to create a list of lists with a specific width for the inner lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a list of lists where my input is a large flattened grid and i need to take the elements in the grid and resize them into smaller lists.
For example, I have a list like this : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and I want to create the list of lists to be [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] where I resized the elements in each inner list to the width (4) in this case. If my list had only 7 elements then  the result should be [[1,2,3,4]] and I should disregard the rest since they won't form another list of width 4. Here  is my code, I am having trouble with "out of global stack" error and I can't figure it out.

code:

```
list_to_llists([],W,L).
list_to_llists([H|T],W,[[X1]|[Xr]]):- 
    length([X1],R),
    R<W,           
    append(X1,H,Rs),
    list_to_llists(T,W,Rs).
list_to_llists([H|T],W,[[X1]|[Xr]]):-
    length([X1],R),
    R>=W,
    append(Xr,H,Rs),
    list_to_llists(T,W,Xr).
```

Comment: You can replace `length([X1],R),` by `R = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
list_to_llists(L,W,[S|R]):-
    length(S,W),
    append(S,T,L),
    !, list_to_llists(T,W,R).
list_to_llists(L,_,[L]).
```

`length(S,W)` *generates* a list of free variables, hence, if such list can be a prefix, just store in results.

You can also try without the cut, to better understand the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, it worked (Y) and i handled the case where the remaining elements are less than the required width.

Comment: I don't want to add the extra element which would make a list less than the required width. For example if my list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and the width is 3  then I want my list to be [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and not [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]. I want to omit the 7, it didn't work for me. So how did you do it? :D

Comment: sorry, I was sure the initial question explicitly requested to add the remaining elements - my bad...